# How to remove an imposed wallpaper?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, administrator, group-policy, desktop-customization

I'm on Windows 7. Recently, someone had my computer and made himself the 'network administrator' He prevented me to change my desktop wallpaper

Even if choose my own, his remains there ... Is there some way to get rid of it? Apparently it has to with a group policy that I, by the way, don't mind deleting.

I have an administrator account.

Comment: Ask him to change it back?

Comment: I can't get in contact with him ... so i have to act alone :/

Comment: [It](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/03/best-practice-using-group-policy-to-configure-desktop-wallpaper-background/) may help.

Comment: Hello,
I found the registry key that was modified to impose this wallpaper on me, will it be safe to remove it ?